# Redirect .htaccess file for old custom post type slug to new slug with post

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type with the slug like this: https://mysitename.org/change-wire/post-name-here. Now the CPT has the slug like this: https://mysitename.org/changewire/post-name-here.

Basically, the slug is changed from **change-wire** to **changewire**. I would like to automatically redirect any  old change-wire.  I think a possible solution is to use the RedirectMatch rule but, but I am not sure if this is right:

I can only do it for one post, but I need to it for all posts

This will work for one: 
`Redirect 301 https://mysitename.org/change-wire/post-name-here https://mysitename.org/changewire/post-name-here`

How to make this work for all posts with change-wire/{post-name} to change changewire/{post-name} ???

`RedirectMatch 301 ???`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using REGEX:

```
RedirectMatch  301 /old-slug/(.*) /newslug/$1
```

In your case

```
RedirectMatch  301 /change-wire/(.*) /changewire/$1
```

Here,

(.*) is a wildcard that matches anything that appears after /old-slug/ and saves it to use in the target URL and $1 outputs the first wildcard from source URL expression.

Comment: Is this working because I am getting the This page isn’t working

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `RedirectMatch` because it makes use of regular expressions :

```
 RedirectMatch  301 /change-wire/(.*) /changewire/$1
```

And if there are more directories like `anything-anything`  , you could do this :

```
RedirectMatch  301 /(.+)-(.+)/(.*) /$1$2/$3
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test and make sure there are no other rules preventing these from being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/change-wire/(.*)$ $1/changewire/$2 [R,L]
```

Hope this will work...