# Wordpress Second Post Type for Post?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type that I imported about 12K records for directly into the database. If I look in the "posts" table there is a field called "post_type" that correctly identifies my CPT. My question is, can I add a second post type for another CPT to the same entry so I don't have to import the same 12k records again? My guess is comma-separating them in the "post_type" field will not work. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just comma separate them. WordPress' [Custom Post Types](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types) take a string as the `post_type` slug when being registered. If you added a comma in there, the post type would be `"this,that"` not `["this", "that"]`.

What you're looking for is using [Taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/) (see also: [Categories, Tags & Custom Taxonomies](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/categories-tags-custom-taxonomies/))

Using a custom taxonomy will allow you to categorically combine/sort custom post types based on whatever definitions you're looking for. Depending on what your post type is, you may want to consider renaming it to something that contains both "post_type_1" and "post_type_2" (since you're trying to combine them) and use those labels as taxonomies, or terms within a single taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you. However, combining and sorting is not my issue. I have custom taxonomies added to the CPT, and when combined with Permalink Manager it allows me to have a custom permalink like /(taxonomy-1)/(post-name)-(taxonomy-2). The problem is, I need another permalink for the same post with something like /(taxonomy-1)/(post-name)-(taxonomy-3).

Comment: You'll most likely need to look at using [WordPress Rewrite Rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) or a [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675478/redirect-htaccess-file-for-old-custom-post-type-slug-to-new-slug-with-post) rule to redirect to handle the second non-existent post type.

Comment: Thank you. I believe you are correct. I actually almost have it solved using add_rewrite_endpoint.